# Did Ivan Drago's wife become friends with Apollo Creed's wife

Tags: rocky-iv

Ludmilla Drago explicitly stated "I hope after, we can be friends." Is there any evidence in the films or novels that they did? It seems unlikely, but after the events of Rocky IV, I could see them being a source of support and healing for one another.

Comment: Well, Im not awere if any material on the subject exists, but maybe the movie "Creed" will let us know.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any evidence to suggest they remained, or rather became, friends. Their exact exchange is as follows:

> **Ludmilla**: Good Luck. I hope, we can be friends.
>   **Mrs. Creed**: I hope so.
>   **Ludmilla**: Of course, they're sportsmen, not soldiers.
>   [Shakes, Mrs.
>   Creed's hand]
>   **Igor Rimsky:** Enjoy the fight
>   [shakes hands with Mrs. Creed]

It appears to just be a friendly gesture, with Ludmilla's line about sportsmen not soldiers drawing a parallel with Rocky's speech at the end of the film. There aren't any interviews with Stallone or other cast members to suggest otherwise.